# How to debug a project in Eclipse, which will result in a plugin for another program?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Just to say it explicit, before someone gets me wrong: I´m not talking about a plugin for Eclipse.

I´m developing a little project, which is just a plugin for another program, which is also written in Java (and available only as a .jar file). I export my project as a .jar file (NOT as a runnable .jar file!). This other program loads this .jar file. The thing is, the main-project isn´t open-source and the developers won´t change that in the near future :/

Until now, I made messageboxes (JOptionPane) and wrote log-files to debug my project. But right now, I´m at a point, where I would like to use the debugger of eclipse. The developers of the main-programm have no clue how to debugg plugins for their project. So I hope that someone here can help me.

Since I can start the main-program via Eclipse (Run as -> Java Application -> main programm), by adding it as an external .jar to the Java Build Path, my first idea was to change the place where the main program saves the plugin .jar files (which can be done by configuration in the program), to the place where eclipse would create it´s "version" of the program (bin folder in the project-path). But then i noticed that it creates only .class files and not the .jar file itself, which brought the sparkle of an idea to an early end...

So how can I use the debugger at such a plugin-project?

Or better: what are the keywords i would have to look-up to find it out by myself, since I get alot of things about plugins for eclipse, when I search for it :(

Comment: If you configure your debug session correctly ie choose the right start point n such I don't see why you shouldn't be able to debug thru eclipse

Comment: One possibility: attach the debugger to an existing process, via Run>Debug Configurations: Remote Java Application. You can specify the location of your source on the "Source" tab.